# Why isn't there a simple syntax for coproduct types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, computer-science, category-theory

Product types in Haskell are easily definable:

```
data Person String String
```

is a product of two types. The coproduct of two types is

```
type Shape=Either Circle Rectangle
```

But whereas the product is easily extendible to three or more types, it doesn't seem so simple for coproducts. Is there a theoretical rationale behind this difference or is the reason purely technical?

Comment: Perhaps I'm thinking of the wrong definition, but I thought coproduct types were also easy: `data Foo = Bar Int | Baz String`

Comment: Thats what I first thought. But Bar & Baz are not types, they're value constructors. If they were types they would have been declared as such by data.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: That's not the point.  `Int` and `String` are types, and `Foo` is the coproduct of `Int` and `String`.

Comment: Or maybe not, I'm going to have to ponder this a bit more.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Yes, that's what I first thought. But the page on [HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hask#Hask_is_not_Cartesian_closed) points out that the Haskell type system does not form a category (but with an easy modification it does), and nor does it have "have sums, products, or an initial object, and () is not a terminal object". They also do not employ the obvious syntax for the coproduct. This is what I'm trying to understand, but probably didn't make clear enough in the question.

Comment: @MoziburUllah That page on HaskellWiki basically seems to be saying (from the best I can gather) is that coproducts are not quite true coproducts because every type can be inhabited by `undefined`. This is technically true. On the other hand, it is usually not conceptually important (though sometimes it is).

Comment: @Owen: The same is true of product types: `(Int, Int)` is not the product of `Int` and `Int` because it also contains `⊥`.  So if you start with the assumption that product types are "close enough", then the same is true of coproduct types.

Comment: @owen: The other point I noticed is that used 'Either' for the coproduct, as the syntax you & Dietrich pointed out would have been my first guess. What exactly is the status of 'undefined' in the haskell type system, I've only just come across it (I'm more familiar with category theory than I'm with Haskell).

Comment: @MoziburUllah: I'm not sure what you think is the "obvious syntax" for the coproduct.  You can't use untagged unions because those are not coproducts.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: The `undefined` value is `⊥`.  In theory, there is only one `⊥`, and it is a member of every non-strict type.  (Different `⊥` can be distinguished using the IO monad.)

Comment: @Dietrich: What do you mean by saying that (Int,Int) contains undefined? What do you mean by 'contains', I know what it means naively. But theoretically I expect it to be a morphism from the terminal element, but according to that wiki-page it doesn't have that either.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: I mean that `⊥ ∈ (Int, Int)`.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: Let us define each *type* to be a set of *values*.  For example, `Bool = { True, False, ⊥ }`.  Note that `⊥ ∈ Bool`.  The value `⊥` is a member of every non-strict type.

Comment: @Dietrich: The obvious syntax is the one Owen pointed out. Is that what you're calling a tagged union?

Comment: @MoziburUllah: Yes, that is a tagged union.  Tagged unions are coproducts, if you ignore `⊥`.

Comment: `data Person String String` is not a Haskell product type.

Comment: Note that `Either` isn't special. It's simply defined as `data Either a b = Left a | Right b`

Comment: The syntax is `data Person = Person String String`. Note the two constructors, type and data. They can have "same" names but they belong to different namespaces.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
data Apple = Gala | Fuji | PinkLady
data Orange = Navel | Blood
data Berry = Blueberry | Cranberry | Raspberry

data Fruit = Apple Apple
           | Orange Orange
           | Berry Berry
```

Here, `Fruit` is a coproduct of `Apple`, `Orange`, and `Berry`<sup>1</sup>.

Note that non-tagged unions are *not* coproducts.

<sup>1</sup>: Well, kinda.  `Fruit` also contains an extra element, `⊥`.  See below.

### Response to edited question

```
data Shape = Either Circle Rectangle
```

You probably mean:

```
type Shape = Either Circle Rectangle
```

If you use `data`, you've defined a product type with a single constructor named `Either`.  This is perfectly legal.  If you use `type`, you've defined `Shape` as another name for `Either Circle Rectangle`, which is a coproduct of `Circle` and `Rectangle`.

### Hask versus Set

Let's call the category of types and functions in Haskell, Hask.  This is the usual name for it.  It does meet the definition for category, assuming you don't look too closely at these finite things we call computers.

And let's compare Hask to the category Set.  This is natural, because Hask is a concrete category.  Compare the `(,)` type constructor in Hask with the cartesian product in Set.  If we want the product of `Int` and `Int`, we get:

- `⊥ ∈ (Int, Int)` (in Hask), but
- `⊥ ∉ Int ⨯ Int` (in Set).

So you can see that the type constructor `(,)` is not the same as the cartesian product, because it contains one extra member, `⊥`.  We can repeat the argument for the disjoint union:

- `⊥ ∈ Either Int Int` (in Hask), but
- `⊥ ∉ Int ⊔ Int` (in Set).

In each case, the structure in Hask contains an additional element, `⊥`, that the equivalent structure in Set would not have.

### Hask versus Pointed sets

Hask is also not the category of pointed sets.  First of all, Hask contains morphisms that are not pointed set morphisms.

1. For every type `T` in Hask, we can construct a function `T -> T` such that `f x = ⊥` for all `x`.  Therefore, `⊥` must be the basepoint, if objects in Hask are pointed sets.  Note that all such `f` are strict functions.
2. However, let `g` be any lazy (the correct term here is actually "non-strict") function.  By the definition of strictness, `g ⊥ ≠ ⊥`.  However, with #1, this contradicts the premise that Hask is the category of pointed sets.

Additionally, the product and coproduct structures are different, in a similar manner to the way the structures are different from the structures of Set.  For products,

- `(⊥, ⊥) ∈ (Int, Int)` (in Hask), but
- `(⊥, ⊥) ∉ Int ⊗ Int` (in Pointed Set).

This follows from the problem with morphisms: in pointed sets, all functions are strict -- this includes constructors such as `(,)`.  The coproduct has the same problem:

- `Left ⊥ ∈ Either Int Int` (in Hask), but
- `Left ⊥ ∉ Int ⊕ Int` (in Pointed Set).

### Conclusion

So, Set and Pointed Set are both not quite equal to the category Hask.  As noted in the [Hask](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hask#Hask_is_not_Cartesian_closed) page on the Haskell Wiki, the "product" and "coproduct" types in Haskell simply don't meet the definition of categorical products and coproducts.  So strictly speaking, products and coproducts don't exist in Haskell.

That's the bad news.  There is good news.

1. Consider all strict functions and strict constructors in Hask.  The result is a subcategory of Hask which is also a subcategory of Pointed Set.  This subcategory is a cartesian closed category.
2. Consider all total functions in Hask, and consider two functions as the same morphism if they produce the same output for every input other than `⊥`.  (These outputs must necessarily not be `⊥` by the definition of "total".)  The result is a subcategory of Set.  This subcategory is a cartesian closed category.

So you can still work with cartesian closed categories as long as you play by the right set of rules.  You even get to choose from two different categories to work with!  However, if you play by these rules, then you are working with a subset of Haskell.

There is a final bit of good news.  Strict functions can be modified into lazy functions without changing the outputs of the program as a whole, assuming the strict version of the program terminates.  So you can pretend that `⊥` doesn't exist and get some work done with category theory, but still write programs that exploit lazy evaluation.

### Summary for the lazy

Pretending that Hask has products and coproducts won't get you into trouble.

Comment: Gala, Fuji etc are not types, they're values.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: I never said that they're types.  `Apple` is a type, and `Orange` is a type, and `Fruit` a coproduct of the two.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: If you want to get technical, you would say that `Gala`, `Fuji`, etc. are nullary constructors.

Comment: I don't think your edit is quite correct. If types always have bottom, then I suspect that they're actually pointed sets. Products & coproducts in the category of pointed sets differ from the set-theoretical cartesian product & disjoint union. Then coproduct there is the wedge sum. (I'm not so sure about the product, it certainly can't be the smash product as that's not associative).

Comment: @MoziburUllah: Hask is not the category of pointed sets.  Morphisms of pointed sets must map the basepoint to the basepoint.  If the basepoint is `⊥`, then this implies that all morphisms (functions) in Hask are strict (this is the definition of "strict").  This is not true, therefore Hask is not the category of pointed sets.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: My edit isn't wrong because I'm making a concrete argument: Hask is not Set.  This is rather straightforward.  I didn't want to duplicate the general argument in the linked article.

Comment: Dietrich: Great answer. But I think in argument 2). of the pointed set case your presentation/reasoning is confusing. Do you not want to say: let 'g' be any lazy function where 'g ⊥ ≠ ⊥', but this contradicts the premise that Hask is the category of pointed sets, which as you say in the comment above, is the category of strict functions? I liked your discussion in this post. Has this been written down more formally anywhere?

Comment: @dorchard: Argument (1) shows that the basepoint must be ⊥, and argument (2) shows that the basepoint cannot be ⊥.  This is intended to contradict the premise that Hask is the category of pointed sets, so you read that correctly.  I haven't seen this written down anywhere, the post just "evolved" out of the discussion for what kind of category Hask is.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Ok, so "By the definition of strictness, g ⊥ ≠ ⊥. " is incorrect. Perhaps you should say "Let 'g' be any lazy function where 'g ⊥ ≠ ⊥'" instead.

Comment: @dorchard: No, a strict function is defined as any function `g` such that `g ⊥ = ⊥` (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_function)).  A lazy function is a non-strict function, so `g ⊥ ≠ ⊥`.  Unless you have a different definition of "lazy" other than "not strict".

Comment: @dorchard: I understand that this is counterintuitive, because it means that `id` is strict even though we know it doesn't evaluate its argument.  However, it is really the only definition of "strict" that I know of.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Apologies, I think you are misunderstanding me. I understand your reasoning, and the definitions, fine. I am simply suggesting that you edit your answer - argument (2) - as you currently say "By the definition of strictness, g ⊥ ≠ ⊥.", which is the *negation* of strictness. This obscures your argument. Perhaps you meant to say "By the definition of non-strictness (laziness)"? Though it should be noted that there *are* some lazy functions where g ⊥ = ⊥ (e.g. g x = ⊥). For your argument, you just need that there exists a lazy function g where g ⊥ ≠ ⊥.

Comment: @dorchard: There are two problems with your suggestion.  First, the major problem: you simply need to re-read the definition of "strict function", because your example of a "lazy function" is actually an example of a strict function!  If `g x = ⊥`, then `g ⊥ = ⊥`, and **by the definition of "strict function",** `g` is a strict function.  Again, *I understand that this is counterintuitive,* but if you cannot supply a definition of "strict function" then you cannot make sound arguments about strict functions.

Comment: @dorchard: The second problem is that I am simply not going to use the phrase, "by the definition of non-strictness".  This is a matter of style.  If we have a definition of "strict function", then we should not need a definition of "non-strict function".

Comment: @dorchard: Finally, I should note that my use of the term "lazy function" is somewhat colloquial.  I hope it is clear from context that I use the term to mean "non-strict function".  Strictly speaking, "lazy" and "eager" are properties of the evaluation system, not of the function; but they are closely associated (culturally) with "non-strict" and "strict" functions, respectively, so I hope the term is not confusing.  I will clarify it in the text.